# get first and last date of 4-week period

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am trying to create a calender table that contains indivudual dates.
For each date a column is present that tells you in which week, isowk, month, quarter and so on thast date belongs.

That is not a big problem. But now we are working with 4-week periods, based on isowk.
So

```
date 2014-12-30 belongs to period 1 which starts on 2014-12-30 and ends on 2014-01-26
date 2014-02-01 belongs to period 2 which starts on 2014-01-27 and ends on 2014-03-02
date 2014-08-05 belongs to period 8 which starts on 2014-07-14 and ends on 2014-08-11
```

It is easy to calculate which period a date belongs to:

```
period_number = ceiling(cast(datepart(isowk,@date) as float) /4 )
```

Finding the start and end of that particular week is not that hard either:

```
start_week = cast(DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,@date),0) as date)
end_week = cast(DATEADD(wk,DATEDIFF(wk,0,@date),6) as date)
```

but how do I calculate the first date of that **4-week** period?

thanks for thinking with me

Comment: What happens with years with 53 ISO Weeks, e.g. 2015-12-28 to 2016-01-03 is week 53 of 2015, does this become its own period, 2015 period 14, or does it spill over into 2016?

Comment: It becomes period 14 but with a label 'Period 1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the start week/end week logic works, then this might work:

```
start_week = cast(DATEADD(wk, 4 * (DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @date) / 4), 0) as date)
end_week = cast(DATEADD(wk, 4 * (DATEDIFF(wk, 0, @date) / 4), 27) as date)
```

I'm not sure why you are using `wk` instead of `isowk` if you want ISO weeks.

Comment: I see now that you are right: for 2012-01-01 f.e. things don't work out :( Suggestions?